# Swift: Xib files Prefix Needed?

Tags: ios, swift, xib

I know Swift classes don't need to add prefix, but how about xib/storyboard files?
For example:
I have a RootViewController.swift and i want to create a xib file, should i name the xib file XXXRootViewController.xib or just RootViewController.xib is OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC the OS will look for a XIB file with the same as that of the view controller. So if you have a `RootViewController.swift` you can load it with `nibName:nil`. In that case the OS will load `RootViewController.xib`

However, I always name it `RootView.xib` (and supply that explicitly as `nibName`) since to me it's not the controller itself but the view description. YMMV